# d3.js Sequence Sunburst __data__ null

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, legend, sunburst-diagram

I am attempting to use a "sequence-sunburst" style d3 visualization for some data that I have. To get started, I decided to simply recreate what is given on the d3 website (http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426).

[image]

It is here that I have run into some issues:

On line 85 in "sequence.js", I get the following error:

`Cannot read property '__data__' of null`

Line 85 has the following code:

`totalSize = path.node().__data__.value;`

Again, to get started, I have copied the js and csv verbatim! I have no idea why this does not work.

Further notes:

- I am using the latest version of Chrome
- I am running Chrome set to `--allow-file-access-from-files`
- I am opening my html file (also copied verbatim!) using python's SimpleHTTPServer. The port is correctly referenced.

Help appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using this with a newer version of D3 that reverses the arguments in the `d3.text` callback. Try defining the callback as `function(error, text) { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm just now returning to my d3 side project. I did as you suggested, but bugs persisted so I just dropped the text-to-json function and used a json file. Other issues have arisen as a result, but my main problem is resolved.